# $_POST array issue

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have this code:

```
$array = 'user_profile';
$var_name = 'postcode';
if ( isset($_POST['user_profile']) ) {
    echo '<br />Var name ('.$var_name.')<br />';
    print '<pre>';print 'Keys<br>';print_r(array_keys($_POST[$array]));print '</pre>';print '<br />';
    print '<pre>';print 'POST user_profile<br />';print_r($_POST[$array]);print '</pre>';print '<br />';
    print '<pre>';print 'POST dump<br />';var_dump($_POST[$array]);print '</pre>';print '<br />';
    echo '<br />{'.$_POST[$array][$var_name].'}<br /><br />';
}
die();
```

And I get this:

```
Var name (postcode)
Keys
Array
(
    [0] => 'address_1'
    [1] => 'address_2'
    [2] => 'address_3'
    [3] => 'address_4'
    [4] => 'address_5'
    [5] => 'postcode'
    [6] => 'phone'
)

POST user_profile
Array
(
    ['address_1'] => Templeton House
    ['address_2'] => 62 Templeton Street, Suite 22
    ['address_3'] => 
    ['address_4'] => Glasgow 
    ['address_5'] => 
    ['postcode'] => G40 1DA
    ['phone'] => 07222222
)

POST dump
array(7) {
  ["'address_1'"]=>
  string(15) "Templeton House"
  ["'address_2'"]=>
  string(29) "62 Templeton Street, Suite 22"
  ["'address_3'"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["'address_4'"]=>
  string(8) "Glasgow "
  ["'address_5'"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["'postcode'"]=>
  string(7) "G40 1DA"
  ["'phone'"]=>
  string(8) "07222222"
}

Notice: Undefined index: postcode in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxx.com\src\controller\app\userController.php on line 153

{}
```

Line 153 is the one with: `echo '<br />{'.$_POST[$array][$var_name].'}<br /><br />';`

I have been all morning trying to find out where is my mistake.

Can somebody help me?. Thanks.

[EDIT]

I made some changes to try to clearify what has been asked. Obviously the code is more long but the bit you see is at the begining of the function. There is nothing else to show you that will help to understand what is hapening. The output is exactly what I get in the browser, even the last brackets, by the way I don't understand why are there, the first one is OK but the second is printed after a NOTICE ???.

Comment: What is the result from line 152? You print the post array. Is that the same array that you have dumped under the title `POST user_profile`?

Comment: IMO, It should work. Could you post a `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` please? Maybe something is wrong in the `postcode` key.

Comment: Is there code you're not showing us? Are you sure you're showing us the correct output to the correct code? Are you sure you haven't forgotten to upload your code changes before testing? I feel like there is something happening here somewhere you're not telling us about.

Comment: Can you post the fields html part?

Comment: The last `{}` is there because you have them in the last `echo` call. The notice is generated before the `echo` is executed.

Comment: JustCarty, yes I used the titles to make it more readeable. Syscall, I have edited the question and you have the dump() after the title POST dump. Cobra_Fast, I have the same impression but I'm working in the localhost and the result is exactly what I get in the browser. The POST comes from a form it is shown normaly and I uncomment the die() before sending it. muecas IMO the HTML is not relevant thus I'm showing the print_r and dump of the received $_POST

Comment: Cobra_Fast, I agree with you with the first {, but the second is after the error so IMO it shouldn't be there....

Comment: It should be there. It's a notice; notices don't abort execution.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently $_POST['user_profile'] has it's keys with additional quotes.

You can access it with

```
$var_name = "'postcode'";
```

or by fixing the form that generates these weird extra single quotes (`'`).

Comment: @Syscall And this is how we learn that `print_r` never adds any quotes around array keys. :-)

Comment: Exact Cobra_Fast.

Comment: I will alway use the dump instead of the print_r. It sounds that print_r is less "profesional", isn't it?

Comment: @Carlos I prefer a `var_dump()`. Also because `false` is not displayed in a `print_r()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes in your keys `["'postcode'"]` :

```
echo '<br />{'.$_POST[$array]["'$var_name'"].'}<br /><br />';
```

Comment: This was my error: in the input I wrote name="user_profile['postcode']" instead of name="user_profile[postcode]". Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry muecas, the HTML was the issue. You were right it's needed.

Comment: You're welcome, and no worries. Don't forget to add the most informations as possible in your next question ;)